# Does null condition is required while checking validation in input

Tags: javascript, null, user-input

I am checking input box validation in java script using if condition.do we also need to check for null. Or we can check only =''.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(txtname==null||txtname=='')  
{
return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify this check to:

```
   if(!txtname){
      return false;
   }
```

This works because `undefined`, '' (empty string) and `null` are == false

See this example:  http://jsfiddle.net/hEeaJ/1/

Comment: Unless it's null, which is at least what _I_ initialise variables to when no immediate value is available.

Answer (score 0):

I think This only is enough:)

```
     if(txtname=='')  
       {
     return false;
       }
```